# Mean Temperature by group month in R

Tags: r, group-by, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean temperature per month of daily records between 1988 to 2020 using the following code:

```
(Temperature_year_month <- (na.omit(database_PE_na) %>% group_by(month) %>% summarise(mean_temp_monthYear = mean(Air.Temp.Mean))))
```

and I got the following results, that I checked in excel and it seems correct:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   month mean_temp_monthYear
   <dbl>               <dbl>
 1     1                11.4
 2     2                13.5
 3     3                17.2
 4     4                21.2
 5     5                26.0
 6     6                31.0
 7     7                33.3
 8     8                32.5
 9     9                29.1
10    10                22.4
11    11                15.4
12    12                10.7
```

However when I do this only for the month of July (month =7). I got a different result:

```
(Temperature_year_month <- (na.omit(database_PE_na) %>% group_by(month=7) %>% summarise(mean_temp_monthYear = mean(Air.Temp.Mean))))
```

```
  month mean_temp_monthYear
  <dbl>               <dbl>
1     7                22.0
```

Someone could explain to me why this happens¿

Comment: The issue might be `na.omit()`. Instead try using `filter(!is.na(Air.Temp.Mean))` and then compute the mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(database_PE_na)[month == 7, 
    .(mean_temp_monthYear = mean(Air.Temp.Mean, na.rm = TRUE))]
```

Answer (score 0):

- For comparison use `==` and not `=`.
- If you want to get `mean` of one month use it in `filter` instead of `group_by`.
- `mean` has `na.rm` argument which can be set to `TRUE` to ignore `NA` values instead of using `na.omit` and removing the complete row.

Use :

```
library(dplyr)

Temperature_year_month <- database_PE_na %>% 
                              filter(month==7) %>% 
                              summarise(mean_temp_monthYear = mean(Air.Temp.Mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: and if I want to add a group_by (year) apart of the filter (month==7)?

Comment: You can add `group_by(Year)` after `filter`.